# How to add dll into GAC having config file

Tags: .net, app-config, gac

I have created class library project into dotnet framework 4.5.
I have added new file - app configuraiton file and connectiong string is mentioned inside as a key/value.

Now, I need to add this dll into GAC and use into some other application.

Please suggest me how i could add this DLL with configuraiton file so, it should work completely ?

NOTE: this dll will be used in some SSIS and other applications. please suggest how i could use configuration file.

Thanks

Comment: Please find added "NOTE" in question.

Comment: How that supposed to change anything? You can't put config files into GAC (at least officially). If you need a config file, it's not necessarily should be located in GAC, you can use a AllUsers directory or the Registry to store configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a short answer - you don't. it's not the way.

If your DLL is kind of sdk, than its **consumers should config** the use of it. If it's part of an application then it may use the installed application's config.

look at other sdk-s (such as [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/)) to get the idea.

Good Luck,

Comment: Additionally, i have provided some of configuraiton properties as browsable property for the dll (so, consumable control will set these prior and those properties will be refer in dll instead of read the configuration file). Thanks.